# Looping VideoReader in Matlab for processing

Tags: matlab, loops, video-processing

I've looked everywhere and I still cannot seem to successfully loop MATLAB's videoreader. I am trying to use MATLAB to process videos and convert them to saved image sequences which I can analyze by binary pixel properties for areas and such. I'm really new to MATLAB so any help would most certainly help.

Here is my code thus far for the image sequence creation. Also this is in R2015a.

```
    function VideoToImageSequence(dirname,doall)

% load up the set of global variables
global settings
inpath = [settings.inpath, '\' , settings.dirname, '\'];
outpath = inpath; 

%list of files
list = dir([inpath, '\*.avi']);
N =length(list);
display(['Found ', mat2str(N), ' movies in ', inpath]);

%Main converter 
for i= 1:N
rootname{i} = list(i).name(1:end-4);
savefile = [rootname{i}, '.mat'];
if exist([inpath, savefile], 'file') && doall==0
    display(['Found analyzed file ', savefile, ' .... skipping']);
    else

    %Directory
    addpath(genpath([settings.inpath,'\', settings.dirname,'\'     ,rootname{i}]));
    workingDir = [settings.inpath,'\' , settings.dirname, '\' , rootname(i)];
    cd([settings.inpath, '\', settings.dirname, '\'])

    filename= rootname(i) ;

    VideoFile = VideoReader(filename) ; 

    ii = 1;

    %Spits out image sequence
     while hasFrame(VideoFile(i))
        img = readFrame(VideoFile(i));
        filename = [sprintf('%03d',ii) '.jpg'];
        fullname = fullfile(workingDir,'images',filename);
         imwrite(img,fullname)    % Write out to a JPEG file (img1.jpg, img2.jpg, etc.)
         ii = ii+1;
     end
end
end
```

Any help you can give would be awesome! Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Do you get any file written from this function? Please describe what is the output you get.

Comment: Whenever I run the program with any listed filename in the "VideoReader" I get errors such as the variable is a struct or str instead of a char variable type with no output at all.  I can't seem to get the file to pull as a char variable in a loop.  Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Any help would still be greatly appreciated.  I've yet to make heads or tails of how to do it.

Comment: Where exactly do these errors occur? What line in particular?

Comment: VideoFile = VideoReader(filename) 

That line fails because it can't seem to read the file name.